# Clicking on an image pastes the url in a text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm a bit stuck on the following matter, I think I have an idea on how to proceed but I'm not 100% sure. I implemented a PHP web scraper to get the data from an URL. As you can see, the images found on the homepage of 9gag and are being properly displayed on the front end.

My question now is, If a user clicks on one of the images, I'd like to have the direct URL from the image being posted in the textfield 'URL' of the first form. Is this done with JQuery/JS? Like an on.click event or something? Any feedback is much appreciated to get me on the way.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the front-end:
[image]

Comment: use jquery on click event

Comment: -- and read the img.src from 'this'...

Comment: jquery or vanilla, onclick event, put `src` attribute in the `value` attribute of the input. Search Google, for tons of examples.

Comment: $('.img_class').click(function(){  $('#text_field').val($(this).attr('src'));  });

Comment: I'm sorry I lost track of this topic, I will update accordingly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$('img').on('click',function(){
  //using id
  $('#url-text-field-id').val($(this).attr('src'));
   //using class
  $('.url-text-field-class').val($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Note:- You need to add jQuery library before this code and add this code on bottom of the page

***Example:-***

```js
$('img').on('click',function(){
  //using id
  $('#url_image').val($(this).attr('src'));
   //using class
  $('.url_img').val($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

```css
img{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://www.futomicdesigns.com/images/home-interior/home-interior-designers-gurgaon/futomic-designs-interior-designers-gurgaon.jpg"><br/><br/>

<input type="text" placeholder="URL" id="url_image"><br/><br/>

<input type="text" placeholder="URL" class="url_img"><br/>
```

Comment: @Moya  glad to help you :):)